# How to test if a radio button is checked in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, button, radio-button

i'm working on a web scraping project with python and selenium ,i'm trying to recover data when the radio button is selected but i failed to do, this is the html code if any of you can help me and thank you 'advance.

```
<input id="choix_formule1_lpd_1" name="choix_formule1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="lpd@@1@@Chambre Double@@20@@DBL@@1524902140" onclick="slectform('1','lpd','1','1')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the id here is unique you can do this:

```
radio_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('choix_formule1_lpd_1')
checked_att = radio_btn.get_attribute("checked")
if("checked" in checked_att):
    print("radio button found checked")
```

**UPD**
The "Chambre Double" checkbox id is `choix_formule1_lpd_2`
"Double Standard" checkbox id is `choix_formule1_lpd_1`
"Double Standard Vue Mer" checkbox id is `choix_formule1_lpd_3`

The "Chambre Single" checkbox id is `choix_formule1_lpd_1`
"Single Standard" checkbox id is `choix_formule1_lpd_2`
"Chambre Single Vue Mer" checkbox id is `choix_formule1_lpd_3`

All these are unique locators

Comment: thank you for your response but i'ts not unique

Comment: OK, if so I need an unique locator. Please provide it. Preferably a link to that page...

Comment: [link]( https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/detail_hotel_224/) you should click on "tarifs & Dispo" so that the radio button will appear

Comment: can't see such element there

Comment: i've added a picture in my question check it please

Comment: Please describe the flow what to select / click in order to see this state.

Comment: i think it's a session probleme so go to [link](https://tn.tunisiebooking.com/) select destination ="Bizerte", dates as you like after button Rechercher an hotel will display click on "+ De Details" and it will appear